# i need to store the jobids of multiple aws glacier initiate-job requests from cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I have the following lines but on loop with different archive ids. AWS documentation does not have any parameters I can think of that would be able to catch the message it sends back.

Following is the line that I call inside a loop

```
aws glacier initiate-job --account-id 9999999999 --vault-name vaultee --job-parameters file://params.json
```

I was wondering if it's possible to catch the output so i can parse it and get the job id of the request. that way when I need to check the status i can just loop through all the job ids

example output

```
[{
  "JobId" : "lskdjfoksdjfa;lkjlk3j2lk24j",
  "ArchiveId": "salskdjflksdjfklsdfas324234",
  "Date" : "date"
},
{
  "JobId" : "5468726w8f465wdf",
  "ArchiveId": "sdf3243523432",
  "Date" : "date"
},
:
:
{
  "JobId" : "kjhdfkjhasdjkfhsakjdfs",
  "ArchiveId": "78678fgdfgsedf",
  "Date" : "date"
}]
```

Comment: What is the example output from the current command?

Comment: @Marcin edited d

Answer (score 1):

You can use [--query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter) and [--output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#text-output) parameters to filter out the IDs.

In your case, the command could be something in the following form (writing from memory, so can't confirm):

```
job_ids=$(aws glacier initiate-job \
--account-id 9999999999 \
--vault-name vaultee \
--job-parameters file://params.json
--query '[*].JobId' --output text)

echo ${job_ids}
```

and then you can iterate over the ${job_ids} in bash checking for their status using different aws cli command.